# Combobox unable to display 2-digits in a line

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt

There is a comboxbox in this ui I did that will displays the values of 1 to 10.

```
class SettingsCombo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self)
        for item in SettingsCombo.VALUES:
            self.addItems(str(item))
```

However, when I execute my code, the number `10` is displayed in two lines - `1` in a line and its `0` is displayed in the other line

Any ideas?

Comment: are you have tried to use QComboBox.setFixedWidth()?

Comment: @TokSoegiharto I do not think it is a width issue, as the width of my combobox is definitely able to accomodate more than 3 digits

Comment: I've past a working code below.  Yes this just about "Items" and "Item".  If you use "Items", comboBox will treat the value as a 2 arguments.

Comment: @TokSoegiharto Hmm, never know that it will make such a great difference though. Shall check out more on it. Thanks!

Comment: yes that's make a big differences.
You can see how that 2 methods work at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QComboBox.addItems (self, item)
```

dont add each item .pass total list to it

```
class SettingsCombo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self)
        self.addItems(map(str,SettingsCombo.VALUES))
```

Comment: Should I still be using `item` in your code `self.addItems(map(str,item))` where the `for` line is removed?

Comment: i used map since it convert all items in item into string.u need to remove for.

Comment: Hmm... But when I tried using it, I got an error stating either there is no `item` defined or `TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration`

Comment: my bad check now! send values sorry

Comment: This time round, I got `NameError: global name 'VALUES' is not defined` as the error. By the way, may I ask why do you put `str` as part of the `map`? I mean isn't `str' string?

Comment: @yan man! thats easy what i meant is send ur values variable. check now

Comment: I think I kind of figure it out. It should be `self.addItems(map(str, SettingsCombo.VALUES))`

Comment: yes it is. Thank you. I guess this is probably due to the `addItem` or `addItems` as you have mentioned. However, may I ask why can `str` be added into the map? Can `str` be considered as a function?

Comment: @yan yes str is builtin function of python https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html read this

Comment: Will read on it. I asked as I am unable to find similar examples to it and hence was confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here the working code:

```
class SettingCombo(QComboBox):
    VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    def __init__(self):
        super(SettingCombo, self).__init__()

        for v in self.VALUES:
            self.addItem(str(v))
```

Do not use *addItems* but use *addItem* instead
if you want use *addItems*, this code will working:

```
self.addItems([str(x) for x in self.VALUES])
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask what is the differences between `addItem` and `addItems`?

Comment: @yan difference is additem adds single item. but additems add total list at a time